# Burninate [stock]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [stock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stock) tag currently has no wiki and only 258 questions, most of them with negative votes. Nearly all of them are about stock market apps or similar subjects, which is not really on-topic and doesn't add anything useful to any of these questions. How is such a tag useful?

Comment: Just found this on my way to post my own burninate request.  Yes, this tag should go.

Comment: @Makoto it popped up again [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41275788/investing-in-microsoft-stocks). If this is hard to get rid off, maybe make stock a synonym of stocks, so we only have 2 problems: stocks and stockquotes?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think that there is a reason to keep around some kind of tag for working with stocks.  Stocks are a specialized kind of data with their own related set of tasks.

As such, I propose that we get rid of [stock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stock) (251) and [stocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stocks) (221) in favor of [stockquotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stockquotes) (126).  Also, unrelated usages of the tag should be burned.

- Questions about working with stock quotes, **TAG** [stockquotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stockquotes)
- Questions about product stock/inventory, **BURN**

We will also need a tag wiki for [stockquotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stockquotes) that explains proper usage.

Comment: That seems reasonable, [tag:stockquotes] sounds specific enough.

Comment: A problem with using "stockquotes" or anything with the word "stock" is that it technically excludes other types of equities such as futures and ETFs. I feel like a tag with a more universal name would be better, but I'm not sure what that could be.

Comment: It is more important that the tag is discoverable and understandable, rather than precisely descriptive.  Particularly since this subject doesn't attract a lot of questions in our community.

Comment: @AlliterativeAlice The more-accurate term you're looking for I believe would be [tag:financialmarkets] _([Wikipedia - Financial Market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_market))_.  As for @‍JasonMArcher's concern, “stock” may be a recognizable term to those outside of the field, but “financial” and “markets” will likely both land more hits coming from those who do this for a living.  _It's a bit like using the term “PCs” with laymen, where experts are going to be searching for “computers” or “laptops”._

Comment: I'm not really convinced "stockquotes" is better than "stocks" here.

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard I think an argument could be made that "stocks" is clear enough.  "Stock" is overloaded though.  "financial" and "market" are also too broad.

Comment: I like "financemarkets" or something like "financemodelling" so that it is clear that we welcome questions about algorithms and datastructures and not about the the markets or stocks themselves.

Comment: Why not use a tag such as "tickersymbol" which does not already exist? Even a simple web search shows that this is used by a number of financial entities for searches within their platform  By using this tag, "Stocks, Mutual Funds, ETFs, Indices and Futures" and any other financial instrument under these can be tagged using the exact same tag while being descriptive of the purpose of each. In fact, even financial bonds have a "tickersymbol". Lastly, some of these negative rated questions are double tagged "inventory" and "stock" (or even just "stock") when only the former applies.

Comment: @ArtB There is already a [`finance`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/finance) tag for questions about financial math/operations.  That probably needs improvement as well, but it is another subject.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment, so forced into "answer":

> I think that there is a reason to keep around some kind of tag for working with stocks. Stocks are a specialized kind of data with their own related set of tasks.

I agree with the general sentiment of this, but also agree with:

> A problem with using "stockquotes" or anything with the word "stock" is that it technically excludes other types of equities such as futures and ETFs. I feel like a tag with a more universal name would be better, but I'm not sure what that could be.

What about `financial instrument` (or even `tradable instrument`)?  Commodities, equity/commodity options, indices, various other derivatives, have many of the same types of development concerns (scale, precision, representation, rounding error, etc.), but are not limited to "stock" issues.

> Why not use a tag such as "tickersymbol" which does not already exist?

I think `tickersymbol` might be too narrow because many financial products exist (and are instruments that have calculable valuation/risk/etc.), that have no "ticker symbol" (as generally understood) e.g. CDO tranches, prop-shop-specific custom bundles, etc.

Comment: If `tickersymbol` is too narrow, please do keep in mind that it is more broad than `stock`, `stocks`, and `stockquotes` as **tickersymbol** can be used to describe anything traded/valued on an **exchange** such as the NASDAQ, NYSE, TSX & others. The potential challenge with using `financial instrument` or `tradable instrument` is the tag could be too broad and may not be easy for users to find without a very thorough wiki description. I don't believe we will easily have a one-size-fits-all for these financial items/instruments into 1 tag & it still comes down to the overall purpose of the tag.